# How to change bitmap globally on canvas in onDraw

Tags: android, drawing

In a customview I override onDraw, and want to draw a line continuously with some time interval.

I use invalidate() in the end to be able to draw next path next time onDraw is hit.

My issue is that I what to insert a new Bitmap into the canvas after some time. But it only changes the bitmap until next time onDraw() is called where the old bitmap is then showed again. Why is that? It seems im only changing the local canvas.

Also be an alternative way to draw a line continuously with a time interval so one could see the line envolve?

Comment: Show your code, don't just describe it.  You could have a variety of problems, depending on how you actually coded things.